# Upload opencart site to server

Tags: php, opencart

After uploading the opencart site from local machine to server I am unable to set the base url of the site.

I have uploaded all the files and database. Made changes to both the config.php and admin/config.php to reflect new domain path.

I have not done any hardcoding so there are no issues of absolute path in website.

However in all the menu items I still get the "**localhost/Directory"** path. Where should I make changes to update this base url path?

The change must be in database only but I dont know which table..there are hundreds of tables. :-(
Actually only the menu items are not linking properly. I am using the journal theme from themeforest if this matter.

Comment: If you are sure config.php constants are set correctly please also check in back-end if System -> Settings -> store URL is set correctly?

Comment: I am unable to get to backend !!

Comment: Well the only variable stored in the Opencart Database is the 'url' column in the 'store' table. Editing it directly is the same as setting it from the back-end. Other than that the database does not any other urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. I did a fresh install of opencart on the server. Uploaded and overwrite the files to the server from my machine. Deleted the fresh database and imported my database on it. Got it solved!!

Jonid Bendo's comment also work's !!

Sometimes clearing the themes cache also works.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly check for a path in PHPmyAdmin I had to update like this before using CMS's when transitioning from localhost to server and the config file didn't make the change to the database.